# How do you SSH in to an Azure VM through an Azure Bastion?

Tags: ssh, azure, terraform, bastion

My initial understanding was that an [Azure Bastion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-overview) acts like a lightweight SSH (and RDP) gateway to resources -- specifically, VMs -- on the same virtual network, rather than provisioning a full VM as a jumpbox. That is, I would expect to be able to do this, from anywhere on the public Internet, to SSH into a VM on the same network:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private.key -J BASTION_IP user@VM_IP
```

Where `BASTION_IP` is the public IP associated with the Bastion resource and `VM_IP` is the internal IP address of the VM in a sibling subnet to the Bastion subnet.

I've set this up in Terraform, using the "Basic" Bastion SKU but, when I try connecting, it times out. In the Azure Poral, there is an option named "Native Client Support" (which needs the "Standard" SKU), exposed as the `tunneling_enabled` argument in the respective Terraform resource. With those changes made, my connection still times out.

Following the [rabbit hole of documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/connect-native-client-windows) suggests that you *have* to use the Azure CLI. Indeed, I can get tunnelling to work using the Azure CLI -- the SSH extension is Windows only, apparently -- but it's a bit of a faff:

```
az login  # I assume there's a way to login unattended
az account set --subscription SUBSCRIPTION_ID
az network bastion tunnel --name BASTION_NAME --resource-group RG_NAME --target-resource-id REALLY_LONG_VM_RESOURCE_ID --resource-port 22 --port 2222 &
ssh -i /path/to/private.key -p 2222 user@localhost
```

Is there a non-proprietary way of SSH'ing into an Azure VM through an Azure Bastion? Or is my assumption on its use-case off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only have two ways to connect to Bastion with SSH, using a local client, and both involve the Azure CLI:

- Using Az Network Bastion Tunnel, as you mentioned, to create a tunnel and then connect however you want
- Using Az Network Bastion SSH to use the native client directly

You could automate this connection if you wanted to connect using a service principal, but assuming you want to connect as a user then it would be a bit of a pain having to store the users credentials and deal with MFA etc.